# Use a vector resource as application icon in android

Tags: android, vector, apk

I am attempting to use a vector resource for ic_launcher icon, android studio uses it without problems and generate one apk that works perfectly on the device. But when I try to upload to the Play Store is rejected due to invalid icon.

Comment: At best, this would only work with `minSdkVersion` of 21 or higher, as older devices do not know anything about vector drawables.

Comment: Ok, but at build time, Gradle creates PNG raster images at various resolutions as descibed [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html). Why all are ok but ic_launcher not?

Answer (score 1):

Play store doesnt recognize that format as they also needs an image for there storage n it's needed to be ico,png,jpeg formats..